# Unable to Sign in with Apple from the iOS app and Supabase Authentication

Tags: flutter, supabase, apple-sign-in

I'm unable to sign in with Apple and Supabase Authentication from my iOS app.

- Created an app with co.xx.mobile as app bundle ID (xx is used here to hide the app name)
- Added "Sign with Apple" in signing and capabilities
- Created "Services ID" and configured URLs for supabase : domain: https://xx.supabase.co and redirect url: https://xx.supabase.co/auth/v1/callback
- Created the key with "Sign in with Apple" selected.
- Generated the secret key using secret_gen.rb script[image]
  credential.authorizationCode and credential.identityToken are not empty
  I got this error:
  flutter: ----------------FIREBASE CRASHLYTICS----------------
  flutter: AuthException(message: Bad ID token, statusCode: 400)
  Any idea how to fix this?

```
Future<AuthResponse> _signInWithApple() async {
    final rawNonce = supabase.auth.generateRawNonce();
    final hashedNonce = sha256.convert(utf8.encode(rawNonce)).toString();
    final credential = await SignInWithApple.getAppleIDCredential(
      scopes: [
        AppleIDAuthorizationScopes.email,
        AppleIDAuthorizationScopes.fullName,
      ],
      nonce: hashedNonce,
    );
    final idToken = credential.identityToken!;
    if (idToken == null) {
      throw const AuthException('Could not find ID Token from generated credential.');
    }
    try {
      return supabase.auth.signInWithIdToken(
        provider: OAuthProvider.apple,
        idToken: idToken,
        nonce: rawNonce,
      );
    } catch (e) {
      throw AuthException(e.toString());
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an change made on the Apple API, and older versions of Gotrue (Supabase Auth server) will throw this error. You can [update the gotrue version](https://github.com/supabase/gotrue/issues/1401#issuecomment-1945673357) manually, or wait until the new version is rolled out.

Comment: Great! Will wait until the new version is rolled out.

Comment: I have upgraded PostgreSQL to the latest version (15.1.1.18) and updated the supabase_flutter package to 2.3.4.  it works now!